# Makefile: Efficient way to make all '.c' files depend on a header file with the same name?

Tags: c, header, makefile

I have a directory with 50 `.c` source files and each one of these `.c` files depends on a `.h` file with the same name plus a common header file.

Example:

```
foo.c depends on foo.h and common.h
bar.c depends on bar.h and common.h
baz.c depends on baz.h and common.h
```

Is it possible to setup this dependency without having to make a separate target for each .c file?

In case it matters, the ultimate output of this Makefile will be a `libfoo.a` library containing each of these `.o` files.

#### Edit

If at all possible I would like to do this with `gnu make` syntax and not have a target for each file whether or not that target was created manually or by something like `makedepend`.

Comment: Look at http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MakeDepend

Comment: I'd like to stay clear of having multiple targets independent of how they are created.  But since I wasn't clear, here is +1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I know this should suffice.

```
%.o: %.c %.h common.h
\tgcc -c $<
```

`\t` is a tab, and the `gcc -c $<` is of course just an example.

Answer (score 4):

```
OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard *.c))
%.o: %.c %.h common.h
    gcc -c $< -o $@

libfoo.a: $(OBJECTS)
    ar rcs $@ $^
```

Comment: Just a tad too late. This is pretty much exactly what I'm doing except I use `$(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $?` and I don't specify the `-o $@` part in the `gcc` line.  +1 for the help.

Comment: Btw, I like the idea of nesting `$(wildcard)` in the pattern sub without the need for a `SOURCES` variable but I can't get it to work.  Maybe you need `$(patsubst)` for this?

Comment: Yep, this works --> `OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard *.c))`

Comment: You are correct.  It seems that the substitution reference and the `patsubst` form are only equivalent when you are transforming text stored in a variable, not when using a nested command.  Editing my answer to fix the mistake.